# nginx basic auth not working in docker-compose

Tags: nginx, devops, basic-authentication, grafana-loki

i'm setting up basic authentication(credential) for loki and promtail using nginx in docker-compose. i have created htpasswd to set the password for loki and promtail andcreated seperate config file for loki and promtail and passing it through volumes.
however its not triggering authentication for loki and promtail

docker-compose.yaml

```
version: "2"

services:
  my-nginx-service:
    image: nginx
    ports:
      - "8098:80"
    container_name: nginx
    volumes:
      - ./config/sites-enabled/loki:/etc/nginx/sites-enabled/loki
      - ./config/conf.d/loki.conf:/etc/nginx/conf.d/loki.conf
      - ./config/conf.d/loki.conf:/etc/nginx/conf.d/promtail.conf
      - ./config/sites-available/default:/etc/nginx/sites-available/default
      - ./config/htpasswd/.htloki:/etc/nginx/.htloki
      - ./config/htpasswd/.htloki:/etc/nginx/.htpromtail

  loki:
    image: grafana/loki:2.0.0
    container_name: loki
    volumes:
      - ./config/loki.yaml:/etc/config/loki.yaml
    entrypoint:
      - /usr/bin/loki
      - -config.file=/etc/config/loki.yaml
    ports:
      - "3100:3100"

  promtail:
    image: grafana/promtail:2.0.1
    container_name: promtail
    user: root
    volumes:
      - ./log:/var/log/test
      - /var/log/system.log:/var/log/root/system.log
      - ./config/promtail-local-config.yaml:/etc/config/promtail-local-config.yaml
    entrypoint:
      - /usr/bin/promtail
      - -config.file=/etc/config/promtail-local-config.yaml
    ports:
      - "9080:9080"
```

loki.conf

```
    server {

       listen 443;

       location / {
          auth_basic  "Protected Area";
          auth_basic_user_file /etc/nginx/.htloki;

          proxy_pass     http://loki:3100;
       }
    }
```

promtail.conf

```
    server {

       listen 442;

       location / {
          auth_basic  "Protected Area";
          auth_basic_user_file /etc/nginx/.htpromtail;

          proxy_pass     http://promtail:9080;
       }
    }
```

has anybody faced this issue?

Comment: Which URL do you want to access?

Comment: i'm trying to access http://localhost:443 for loki and http://localhost:442 for promtail

Comment: But in your `docker-compose.yaml` you have configured `8098:80`… you'd need to change `listen 443;` to `listen 80;` and then access http://localhost:8089…

Comment: i'm getting nginx welcome message in localhost:8098 after adding ```listen 80;```

Comment: Try with `listen 80 default_server;`.

Answer (score 0):

Apparently, I forgot to rebuild the container images after including the .htpasswd files. Rebuilding fixed this

`docker compose up --build`